# deploy richfaces 4.5.17 web project in tomcat 10

Tags: richfaces, java-11, tomcat10

I am trying to deploy richfaces 4.5 web project in tomcat 10 but getting error (it was working fine in tomcat 9)

- changed all imports (javax -> jakarta)
- tomcat 9 run on servlet 4 and tomcat 10 run on servlet 5
- richfaces 4.5 and jsf 2.2.20 jars are added in mvn dependency

Does anyone maybe have a good idea what is going wrong here or deployed successfully ?

Thanks!

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1027)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2001)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:828)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1708)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:320)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:886)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:437)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:934)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHos
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type specified [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener] is not
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1151)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.addListener(ApplicationContextFacade.java:662)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5168)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

Comment: This doesn't look like a RichFaces issue, but `Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHos` (not StandardHost) is suspicious.

Comment: This won't work. RF is old. Totally different technological stack. RF depends on old Java EE 6. Look at dependencies in Maven.